# Merge [product-key] and [license-key]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[product-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-key) and [license-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license-key) tags seem to be synonyms.

Comment: I can't think of a joke to honor the tradition. Feel free to submit your proposals :)

Comment: Should we put these keys in a ring?

Comment: @Vylix `Should we put these [product-key]s and [license-key]s on a [keychain]?`

Answer (score 1):

No. Product could be subsystem of Licence (if Licence covers few Products).

Comment: In this case the parent `license-key` should be fine. Let's not be overspecific.

Comment: in tha case - yes, merge product to license